# Web based Multithread downloader in C# Asp.net

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, html, multithreading

We have an application which offer big file download and upload feature.

Currenly, we are doing upload using java applet and download using c# windows application but now the requirement is web based (html5/javascript) downloader.

Please advise. Is it possible to develop javascript based multi-threaded download manager?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you are looking for SOCKET.IO(http://socket.io/) or WebSocket.

Comment: Thanks for your replay.. I am going to RnD on WebSocket.

Comment: You are welcome.  There is one issue that you should be aware of, not all the browser support WebSocket. Maybe you need to ajax when websocket is not available.